# Why gives my matrix multiplication between 2d and 1d array this result?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

Example:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1., 2., 3.], [4., 5., 6.]])
y = np.ones(3)

np.dot(x , y)
```

Result:

```
array([ 6., 15.])
```

How is this possible when I have a matrix of (2x3) by (1x3)? It should be a 3x1 matrix.

Comment: In numpy there's a difference between 1d and 1 row 2d arrays. (3,) , (1,3), (3,1) are different shapea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`y` is not a 1x3 matrix but a 1-D vector (check `y.size` if in doubt). If you have a look at the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) you can find

> If a is an N-D array and b is a 1-D array, it is a sum product over the last axis of a and b.

That's why it is returning a 1-D vector of two elements.

Answer (score 0):

In a `dot` product, the length of the last dimension of the left-side array should be identical to the length of the second-to-last dimension of the right-side array.

You can [`transpose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) `y`, if this makes sense in terms of your computation:

```
y = np.ones(shape=(1, 3))

out = np.dot(x , y.T)
```

Output:

```
array([[ 6.],
       [15.]])
```

Or convert back to 1D:

```
out = np.dot(x , y[0])

# or
out = np.dot(x , y.squeeze())
```

Output: `array([ 6., 15.])`

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the dot product of a 2D array and a 1D array (or vector) here. In numpy there is no distinction between row and column vectors. So in your example the vector is treated as a column vector. See [here](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/absolute_beginners.html#more-information-about-arrays) for more information.